# Form validation / Field validation in AngularDart fails without error message

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In Angular JS I can do something like this:

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="control-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm['name'].invalid}">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="project.name" ng-required="true">
    <span class="help-block">Required</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

`myForm.invalid` works perfectly but the field check does not.

I'm missing something or is it just not implemented jet? (Agualar: 0.12.0, Dart: 1.5.8)

**[ Update ]**
To minimize my sample I've removed the `<fieldset>` I originally had in my code - this caused the error - or the problem!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the updated question - `fieldset-tag` causes the problem.

So first of all: ** The above sample (question) works! **

If you are using a `fieldset` the validation-checkt must be:

```dart
<form name="myForm">
    <fieldset name="fields">
      <div class="control-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm['fields']['name'].invalid &&
           myForm['fields']['name'].dirty}">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block">Required</span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```